# wp_remote_request to remotely get a file only accessible to logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, shopp

I'm developing a plugin which has an upgrade option. After the customer purchases the plugin from my sales site (also running Wordpress), they get a download key and download URL generated by Shopp. For example:

```
$url = 'https://mysalessite.com/products/account/download/5cad290d109a519cdbdb6197307bd378ae1aa25f/';
```

I'd like the client to be able to enter their user name, password, and download key into the plugin options and receive the upgrade package automatically. But, obviously, when I use:

```
$response = wp_remote_request( $url ); 
var_dump( $response );
```

The only thing that is returned is the login screen, since the user isn't logged in.

I stumbled upon the suggestion at http://lud.icro.us/wordpress-http-api-basicauth, and tried using

```
$args = array(
     'headers' => array(
          'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username:passw0rd' )
     )
);
$response = wp_remote_request( $url, $args );
```

But it still returns a login screen in `$response`, not the purchased file.

Comment: Hello, that depends on how you are login your users in the remote script (page). If your remote script has a login form that "Post" the values of username and password, you should do the request to that page passing those values using Post method too. I'm not sure how you are receiving the request in your Download URL, depends on how you authenticate your users in that Download page. You can specify more and I can help you more precisely.

Comment: @gsc-leticia, I should have been more specific: both sites are Wordpress.I can pass the username and password to wp-login.php on the sales site, but only as a URL parameter. Isn't sending a password as a URL parameter generally considered to be a bad practice (insecure)?

Comment: definitively, you should try to use Post method instead of Get (passing the variables in the URL) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post

Comment: If the Download Key is unique and private, I normally use it to identify the user request. I don't know specifications of your App, but for most of mine that Download Key is enough, so you can do a page that receive that Key and return the information/file you want.

Comment: @bcorkins what was the solution to this?  It would be helpful to others if you answered your own question.